# Mapping some work item fields to Comments

Tags: azure-pipelines, vsts-sync-migrator

I am trying to move work items from OnPrem TFS server 2017 to Azure DevOps Services. I use the VSTS Sync Migrator and this tool works like a charm.

My question: Is there any way to map certain fields from OnPrem server to Comments section? I have few list of fields which are not appropriate for Azure DevOps Services fields, but still wanted to have this data available in Azure DevOps.

I see that Comments/discussion section is not a field in Azure DevOps. Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked the reply below? Is it helpful?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT, I could not able to update Comments with specific field data. It would be helpful if configuration setting is provided (say Story Points from Feature to Feature Comments). I didn't find any documentation for adding table with fields data in Comments

Comment: Could you provide an example of what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments field is actually there and is "System.History" however that might not be the best place for it.

There is an option to have the tool create a JSON with all of the fields and attach it, or to add a table to the comments section with all of the field values.

> [Work item migration Documentation](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Processors/WorkItemMigrationConfig.html)
>
> **Param:** BuildFieldTable
>
> **Type:** Bool
>
> **Description:** Add in the original field to value table in a history comment. So if you lost information with the field mapping you are on
> the save side without data lost.

You will need to experiment with the options to see what suits.

Comment: I could not able to update Comments with specific field data. It would be helpful if configuration setting is provided (say Story Points from Feature to Feature Comments). I didn't find any documentation for adding table with fields data in Comment

Comment: https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Processors/WorkItemMigrationConfig.html

BuildFieldTable: Add in the original field to value table in a history comment. So if you lost information with the field mapping you are on the save side without data lost. This table is searchable using a CONTAINS WIQL query

Comment: Thank you MrHinsh - Martin Hinshelwood. This helped me to update the values in comments section.